# order by and group by both at time not working

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, sql-order-by

My query is below

```
SELECT *
  FROM
(
SELECT
    usr.*,
    messages.message_text, messages.message_id
FROM
    `user` as usr
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        message.*
    FROM
        message AS message
    ORDER BY
        message.updated_at
    DESC
 ) AS messages
ON
`usr`.`user_id` = `messages`.`sender_id` OR `usr`.`user_id` = `messages`.`receiver_id`
WHERE
`usr`.`is_delete` = 0 AND `usr`.`is_active` = 1
ORDER BY
messages.updated_at
DESC
) AS result
GROUP BY
    result.user_id
```

if i remove the group by then it work well , but i want the result with group by Please Help.

I have one message table in that i have saved the sender id and receiver id, both id have foreign key with user table and i want the recent message send by user and user details
So for latest message i am using order by desc and after getting all the messages with descending order i am using group by but it is not working.

Answer (score -1):

It was very hard making the table schemas and the data insert in them which would act like your scenario. So next time, please provide a fiddle link to your schema/situation.

Here were the issues in your query:

- You dont need a subquery after `LEFT JOIN`
- `ORDER BY` clause is always after `GROUP BY`
- You must mention all the columns that you are `SELECT`ing in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Tweaked your query a bit:

```
SELECT *
  FROM
(
    SELECT
        usr.*,
        messages.message_text, messages.message_id, messages.updated_at
    FROM
        user as usr
    LEFT JOIN message messages
        --(
        --  SELECT
        --      message.*
        --  FROM
        --      message AS message
        --  ORDER BY
        --      message.updated_at
        --  DESC
        --) AS messages
    ON
    usr.user_id = messages.sender_id OR usr.user_id = messages.receiver_id
    WHERE
    usr.is_delete = 0 AND usr.is_active = 1
    --ORDER BY
    --messages.updated_at
    --DESC
) AS result
    GROUP BY
    result.user_id,result.name,result.is_delete,result.is_active,result.message_text,result.message_id,updated_at
    ORDER BY
    result.updated_at
    DESC
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Performance benefits aside, in the absence of any aggregating functions a GROUP BY clause is never a good idea.

Comment: Also, it seems odd to go to the trouble of creating the schema to then not share it.

Comment: Please have a look at the question again. He wants to the run his query with group by. The query had errors. which have been resolved in the query I posted in the answer.

Comment: If i remove the left join then the problem is, i am getting the records but i want last record of message table of that particular id

Comment: If you think there couldve been a better query, Please post it as answer.

Comment: I think we should appreciate the efforts put forward by the people who answer the queries

Comment: I will take care of posting the schema as well from the next time. Unfortunately, I removed after completing the query that I posted